# Facebook like an object

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-sdk-4.0

Need help with Facebook SDK Php Facebook Like.

My website fetches Logged in FB User's Timeline and user can Like posts in his timeline.
Posting Likes works for me successfully. But my question is how should I know he had already liked the post.

I want to show Like button if he has not liked that object and unlike button if he has already liked it.

PS: I tried collecting all the list of users who liked and then compared it with logged in user's fb id, but this method takes long time if likes are more than 10k.

Is there any other methods to accomplish this task.
I am using `facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev`

PS: My code for showing his feed is:

```
(new FacebookRequest($session, 'POST',"/me/feed", $params))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this will help you

```
$fql= "select user_id from like where object_id=REQUIRE_OBJECT_ID_HERE AND user_id=me()";
$request = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', "/fql?q=$fql"))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

Change REQUIRE_OBJECT_ID_HERE variable to the id that you need.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution available now is looping through the list of likes like you do , as of now .

there is another solution using FQL

```
select user_id from like where object_id=your object_id AND user_id=me()
```

but the problem is that he LIKE table only considers videos, notes, links, photos and albums, not posts.
check [facebook fql like documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/) . also note that fql is on track for full deprecation .

Comment: Thanks, But now I am facing another issue....The User Id that I get from /me is different from the one that of Likes id.. For example My id shown  using /me is 1548231432059768 and when I get use GET',"/".$Likeid."/likes?limit=$count" I get different id.. But the Name is mine... How is that different...